# Sklearn K-Fold Cross Validation Memory Issues

Tags: python, memory, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I'm trying to run some supervised experiments with a simple text classifier, but I'm running into memory issues in using the `K Fold` generator in `Sklearn`. The error I'm getting is states: "Your system has run out of application memory", but my dataset is only ~245K rows x ~81K columns. Large-ish, sure, but not huge. The program never terminates, but rather "hangs" until I manually shut down the terminal app. I've let it run like this for about 30 minutes, with no progress.

I've also written in `print` statements to see where in the cross validation for-loop the code gets stuck. It looks like the indices for training and test sets are generated, but the code never gets to the point of slicing off the actual training and test sets for features and labels using these indices. I'm running this on a Macbook Pro running 10.9.5. I've run this shutting down every other app except the Terminal app, with no success. Has anyone else had problems with this or is this likely something specific to my machine?

**EDIT**: I've run this with 10-fold and 5-fold cross validation and run into the same problems each time.

Comment: Simple question are you running 64-bit version and how much memory do you have on your laptop?

Comment: Thanks for looking @EdChum. I'm running the 64-bit version and have 8 GB of memory.

Comment: Another simple question - can you run it on the training set with CV? That is, is the CV that is causing the problem?

Comment: Hey @AmiTavory. I think the issue is with actually indexing into the training and test sets. For instance, in my CV for-loop if I just write print statements to print out the arrays of indices for each fold of cross validation, this works no problem. However, if I run the same for-loop and instead try to index into the dataset for training and test sets using the indices generated by the `KFold` object, my code never gets past the first fold of cross validation. I hope that answers your question.

Comment: @kylerthecreator my question had a typo: I meant "can you run it *without* the CV". IIUC, your answer addresses this partially, as you say that even the indexing is a problem. Just for some more info, though, perhaps you could check if you can run the text classifier on the entire dataset without CV.

Comment: @AmiTavory got it. The indexing does appear to be the problem. The code I've run hasn't even gotten to training the classifier as I haven't even been able to split the full dataset into training and test sets (I've been trying to run this with logistic regression - no parameter tuning, nothing fancy). I ran the CV with a smaller dataset of 100K instances and it did not work. Ran with just 1,000 instances and it finally worked. I'm wondering if there are simply too many features with around 245K instances. Even running with the `train_test_split()` function does not work on the full dataset.

Comment: @kylerthecreator Yes you are realizing there are a lot of features for 250K instances. You can think about it this way: a 250K x 80K matrix has the same number of elements as a 250M x 80 matrix. Now that may sound a bit bigger to you ;). Could you add the code you are using so we can see the data structures you're using, etc?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the first issue comes from this part:

> my dataset is only ~245K rows x ~81K columns. Large-ish, sure, but not huge.

245K x 80K does not sound huge, but let's just do the math and assume 8 bytes per element stored.If your matrix is not sparse (obviously in your case it is a sparse matrix), that would be 245 * 80 * 8 MB so roughly **160 GB** that need stored in your RAM. This is actually huge!

You mention text classification so I'm guessing your features are tf-idf or counts of words and that it is very sparse. What you need to be wary about now is to keep the sparsity at each step and to use only algorithms that **work with sparse data** and that will not allocate a dense matrix of size `n_samples * n_features`.

Naive bayes classifiers (see `sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB` for instance) have had decent success in text classification, I would start there.

Such a classifier can easily handle 250K x 80K matrix as long as it is a sparse matrix (and is actually sparse enough of course).

If you still want to reduce the number of features you get from tf-idf you have several options:

1. Remove stop words, either with a stop words list or by setting the `max_df` parameter to a value around 0.7 or lower (this will discard any term that is in more than 70% of the documents).
2. Apply feature selection before training your classifier. [This scikit-learn example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/text/document_classification_20newsgroups.html) shows how to use the chi-squared statistics to select features based on sparse data.
3. Apply dimensionality reduction techniques such as SVD (I'd look into [Latent semantic indexing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_semantic_indexing), but I am not proficient with this).

The options 1. and 2. combined should already allow you to significantly reduce the number of features.

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: much agreed. 245K rows look fine, but 81K columns is crazy. Maybe do a dimensionality reduction first.